# Python nested dictionary to tree structure dictionary (json)

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, tree

I am trying to structure my data from a df to nested dict and to a tree structure.
I want to have keys and children for each node and I am trying to have it for three levels, 1, 1.1 and 1.1.1 to display in one Flask app.

(I already did some research and tried to use defaultdict from collections, I am trying this approach once its what took me almost there. If theres a better approach I will be happy to accept it. thanks in advance for your help)

```
df =pd.DataFrame({
'Country': ['Germany', 'Germany', 'Canada', 'Canada'], 
'PopulationEst': [8, 4, 35, 50], 
'Continent': ['Europe', 'Europe', 'North America', 'North America']},
columns=['Continent','Country','PopulationEst'])
```

then I generate my nested dict:

```
mydict = {}
for lst in df.values:
    leaf = mydict 
    for path in lst[:-2]:
       leaf = leaf.setdefault(path, {})
    leaf.setdefault(lst[-2], list()).append(lst[-1])  

mydict= {'Europe': {'Germany': [8L, 4L]}, 'North America': {'Canada': [35L, 50L]}}
```

I am trying to achieve the following output:

```
{'key':'Europe', "children":[
      {'key': 'Germany', "children":[8L, 4L]}
             ]},
'key':'North America', "children":[
      {'key': 'Canada', "children": [35L, 50L]}}}
```

Using dict comprehension:

```
final_dict = {outer_k: {inner_k: {'key':inner_k, 'value':inner_v} for inner_k, inner_v in outer_v.items()} for outer_k, outer_v in mydict.items()}
```

I am getting the following output:

```
Out[2]: 
{'Europe': {'Germany': {'key': 'Germany', 'value': [8L, 4L]}},
'North America': {'Canada': {'key': 'Canada', 'value': [35L, 50L]}}}
```

Comment: Your example code breaks here for me: 

    leaf = result

Comment: sorry @David its fixed, my mistake it should be leaf = mydict  not result

Comment: 4 observations: a) what is the actual format of your original data? b) the output you ask for is a bit peculiar, to me it looks like you have a double key in the root, that won't work. c) have you looked into using a library for trees, there are plenty of them out there (networkX is one). d) why the structure of the output, i.e. what is the "consumer"? json to browser and js for charting?